# How does a programme with same clrscr(), i.e clrscr command with comma operator

Tags: c

There are two similar programs with just change in position of `clrscr(),`; one will show error and other will execute without any error.

For example, this executes:

```
   void main()
   {
   int a,b,c;
   clrscr(),
   printf("Enter the numbers");
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
   printf("%d",c)
   getch();
   }
```

But this program has an error:

```
   void main()
   {
    clrscr(),
   int a,b,c;
   printf("Enter the numbers");
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
   printf("%d",c)
   getch();
   }
```

Why is that?

Comment: In c89 all automatic variables must be defined at the very beginning of the enclosing block and before any other statement.

Comment: but the clrscr(), command is performing its function in first programme despite declaring after defineing

Comment: can you plzz elobrate ??

Comment: First does not have any "declaring after defining". It has a statement which evaluates clrscr(), ignores the return value, evaluates printf() and ignores that return value, too, in a different way. Second program has a variable definition too late and on top of that where an expression is expected.

Comment: Why don't you add what error you get. Then we can confirm that you are trying 21st century C systax in a C compiler written around 1985.

Comment: I'm surprised either versions of the code compiles when they're missing a semicolon after the 2nd `printf`

Comment: This question was already [previously closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515597/how-does-a-program-can-run-with-clrscr-command-and-without-clrscr) for being unclear and not posting the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ChrisTurner Well spotted, I picked that up in my answer. Hope you do not mind.

Comment: @Yunnosch it probably also needs to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: @WeatherVane Hmm, I find it a perfectly clear "I need to read a book" question. The problem can easily be explained otherwise.

Comment: "I see an error".  **Tell us what you saw**.  This is not youtube.com

Comment: @HansPassant , I find the solution thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using (and perhaps abusing, since you probably should not use it like you do) the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

That comma operator is binary and works on two expressions ( its left and right operand). !It first evaluates its left operand (for side effects only), then its right operand (which is the result of that comma operator application).

In your code (your 2<sup>nd</sup> example), you don't have an expression, but a declaration, at right of the comma (after `clrscr()`). So this is a syntax error.

Of course your last `printf` lacks a semi-colon. I guess it is a typo.

Take the habit of reading documentation (notably of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), but also of `clrscr` which is non-standard); compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

Of course, your `main` is wrong. It should return an `int`. Look into some [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site, and then into the C11 standard, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (a draft nearly identical to the standard).

Answer (score 0):

First does not have any "declaring after defining".
It has a statement which evaluates clrscr(), ignores the return value, evaluates printf() and ignores that return value, too, in a different way.
Second program has a variable definition too late and on top of that where an expression is expected.

```
void main()
   {
   int a,b,c; /* define vars, fine */
   clrscr(), /* evaluate clrscr(), then ignore the return value ... */
   /* expect another expression,
      the value of which to be the total result of the "," operator */
   printf("Enter the numbers"); /* there is an expression, fine */
   /* the total result gets ignored, also fine */
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
   printf("%d",c); /* added ";" */
   getch();
   }

   void main()
   {
    clrscr(), /* code before variable definition, fishy */
    /* expecting an expression ... */
   int a,b,c; /* no expression fishy, 
     a variable definition - too late, fishy */

   /* statement/definition above terminated with ";", fine,
      if not for all the fishy stuff before. */
   printf("Enter the numbers");
   scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
   c=a+b;
   printf("%d",c) /* missing ";" probably irrelevant */
   getch();
   }
```